# How can I get more options for a rule that only allows "is/is not"?

Tags: attributes, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have an attribute (strength) that has 5 levels. For a sale (shopping cart rule) we want to try and sell the higher level options for 70% off.

So when I was testing I only could get the coupon to work with just one option at a time (is/is not). When I added the others on another line, it became invalid at checkout.

Is there a way to say is "1 of these" and then option 1, 2, 3... For category it is nice because you can add multiple categories.

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved by changing the rule so that it reads as follows:

if All of these conditions are TRUE
-> If an items is FOUND in cart with **ANY** of these conditions true
->-> strength is level1
->-> strength is level2

That way, it will apply if any of the matched levels are there, instead of only applying if all of them are there which, if your attribute is a dropdown, will never be able to match as it will only ever have one value.

The below screenshot illustrates this with a different attribute:

[image: Multiple attributes on rule]